# Can't update django to newest version

Tags: python, django, unix

I am a django beginner trying to set up django newest version 2.0.2 in my virtual environment. I am running python 2.7 on my mac, currently using django 1.01.It wouldn't allow me to update any other versions.When I do pip install django==2.0

```
Collecting django==2.0
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django==2.0 (from versions: 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.2.4, 1.2.5, 1.2.6, 1.2.7, 1.3, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.5, 1.3.6, 1.3.7, 1.4, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.4.5, 1.4.6, 1.4.7, 1.4.8, 1.4.9, 1.4.10, 1.4.11, 1.4.12, 1.4.13, 1.4.14, 1.4.15, 1.4.16, 1.4.17, 1.4.18, 1.4.19, 1.4.20, 1.4.21, 1.4.22, 1.5, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.4, 1.5.5, 1.5.6, 1.5.7, 1.5.8, 1.5.9, 1.5.10, 1.5.11, 1.5.12, 1.6, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.6.5, 1.6.6, 1.6.7, 1.6.8, 1.6.9, 1.6.10, 1.6.11, 1.7, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.7.4, 1.7.5, 1.7.6, 1.7.7, 1.7.8, 1.7.9, 1.7.10, 1.7.11, 1.8a1, 1.8b1, 1.8b2, 1.8rc1, 1.8, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 1.8.4, 1.8.5, 1.8.6, 1.8.7, 1.8.8, 1.8.9, 1.8.10, 1.8.11, 1.8.12, 1.8.13, 1.8.14, 1.8.15, 1.8.16, 1.8.17, 1.8.18, 1.9a1, 1.9b1, 1.9rc1, 1.9rc2, 1.9, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.9.4, 1.9.5, 1.9.6, 1.9.7, 1.9.8, 1.9.9, 1.9.10, 1.9.11, 1.9.12, 1.9.13, 1.10a1, 1.10b1, 1.10rc1, 1.10, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.3, 1.10.4, 1.10.5, 1.10.6, 1.10.7, 1.10.8, 1.11a1, 1.11b1, 1.11rc1, 1.11, 1.11.1, 1.11.2, 1.11.3, 1.11.4, 1.11.5, 1.11.6, 1.11.7, 1.11.8, 1.11.9, 1.11.10)
No matching distribution found for django==2.0
```

Comment: check this [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/) : "The Django 1.11.x series is the last to support Python 2.7."

Comment: If you want to install the latest version of 1.11.x try `pip install django<=2.0` which should work with Python 2,7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually `django-2.0` is not supported by python2.

**The Django 1.11.x series is the last to support Python 2.7.**

Thatswhy you are getting the **error matching distribution**.

You can have a look on django-2.0 [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/).

Comment: @YikoMinxuanLi, as python2.7 doesn't support django-2.0, you need to use python3 and also `pip3` for virtual environments and packages installing.

Answer (score 1):

django 2.0 needs python3. I recommend moving to python3

Answer (score 0):

To update it go to your command prompt and type (can type cmd in search box to open):

```
pip install --upgrade django==4.0.2
```